# How to put two form elements in a row using Drupal Form API?

Tags: forms

I am creating a form in Drupal 6 using form API.

I need to put a textfield and a select next to each other. they are for entering something like 'www.domainname.com' . www. is fixed. domainname section is given from user in a textfield and .com section is chosen from select element by user.

So they should be in a line. but as I see I can put these two form elements in a line, they are in their div container.

Would you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a CSS issue. All you need to do is limiting the width of both elements and then float them to the left; this will make them inline. Be sure to wrap them both in a div with the "clearfix" class to clear the float.